# Can I use a C# dll with unsafe code in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, pixel, unsafe

There is an FastBitmap class for C#, that lets you acces and modify pixel information of am bitmap. I have already used it in some C# project, but I need it now in VB.NET.
The problem is that that class uses unsafe code, that is not supported in VB.NET.

The question is. Can I compile the FastBitmap class in a dll and use it in VB.NET?

[EDIT]
Or is there  some library that can be used to modfy pixel data in VB.NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

If the class doesn't expose any *unsafe* features in its public interface (e.g. method taking a pointer) then you shouldn't have any problems using it from VB.NET. The common language runtime (CLR) supports unsafe code, so C# doesn't do any *magic* when you write unsafe programs.

If you wanted, you could also reimplement the `FastBitmap` class in VB.NET using the [Marshal class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx), which gives you fast access to memory using a standard .NET interface accessible from VB.NET as well. But the ability to mix multiple languages in a single project is a great advantage of .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Fast answer, **yes**. By the way, did you try it?

Comment: No, I didn't try it. I was busy at the moment that I came with the idea and didn't have time to experiment.