# How can I use unsafe code in VB.Net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, unsafe

I would like to know the VB.NET equivalent of the following C# code:

```
    unsafe
    {
        byte* pStart = (byte*)(void*)writeableBitmap.BackBuffer;
        int nL = writeableBitmap.BackBufferStride;

        for (int r = 0; r < 16; r++)
        {
            for (int g = 0; g < 16; g++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < 16; b++)
                {
                    int nX = (g % 4) * 16 + b;                            
                    int nY = r*4 + (int)(g/4);

                    *(pStart + nY*nL + nX*3 + 0) = (byte)(b * 17);
                    *(pStart + nY*nL + nX*3 + 1) = (byte)(g * 17);
                    *(pStart + nY*nL + nX*3 + 2) = (byte)(r * 17);
                 }
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: You could put it in a C# assembly and reference it from your VB.NET project.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307433/can-i-use-a-c-dll-with-unsafe-code-in-vb-net/2307448#2307448 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Not possible, since vb.net does not support unsafe code.***

Comment: You shouldn't answer your own question by copying someone else's answer. Just accept Bala R's answer instead.

Answer (score 31):

Looks like it's not possible.

From [this post](http://www.dnjonline.com/article.aspx?ID=mar05_vbvscsharp)

> VB.NET is more restrictive than C# in
>   this respect. It does not permit the
>   use of unsafe code under any
>   circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

VB.NET does not allow use unsafe code, but you can do your code in safe managed:

```vb
Dim pStart As IntPtr = AddressOf (writeableBitmap.BackBuffer())
Dim nL As Integer = writeableBitmap.BackBufferStride

For r As Integer = 0 To 15
    For g As Integer = 0 To 15
        For b As Integer = 0 To 15
            Dim nX As Integer = (g Mod 4) * 16 + b
            Dim nY As Integer = r * 4 + CInt(g \ 4)

            Marshal.WriteInt32((pStart + nY * nL + nX * 3 + 0),(b * 17))
            Marshal.WriteInt32((pStart + nY * nL + nX * 3 + 1),(g * 17))
            Marshal.WriteInt32((pStart + nY * nL + nX * 3 + 2),(r * 17))
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: This is not the same. Unsafe code allows the use of pointers, this managed code uses references. References are significantly slower than pointers.

Comment: who care about 0.00001sec and 0.00002sec?

Comment: Using pointers is not just half the time of using references.

Comment: Hi bro, your eye don't see anything when it running the code. why you are still feeling bother?

Comment: That's like saying a bubble sort is the same as a quick sort just because your eye can't see any difference with a small set of items.

Comment: I don't want to waste my time to this conversation my friend. as I said 0.00001 and 0.00002 is nothing to end user. Even 1sec to 2sec is still acceptable.

Comment: This isn't much of a conversation. References are significantly slower than pointers. The question was how to use unsafe code in vb.net and your answer answer is to use managed code. Managed code is very different than unsafe code and is MUCH slower than "just" double the time. I don't know why you refuse to accept the fact. You can deny it all you like but that won't change reality. And your comments indicate that you have no experience at all writing scalable software that needs to perform well under load.

Comment: VB.Net does not allow unsafe code, and the managed VB.Net code in your answer is not the same as unsafe code in C#. Period. I don't know why you're still going on about this.

Comment: Also might be worth me pointing out - your code doesn't compile.  You can't use `AddressOf` on an object like that; `AddressOf` only works with the name of a method.

Comment: Change the bounds of your loops to something much larger and you will notice a difference. This answer is garbage.