# Why can't you develop XNA games in VB.Net?

Tags: .net, xna

I know there's no VB.Net project type for the XNA games but as a simple test, I threw together a VB Solution which references `Microsoft.XNA.*`. It has a class which implements `Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Game`. Then in the C# `Game1.cs`, I simply removed all the boilerplate code and modified it to inherit from my VB class...

```
namespace MyGame {
    public class Game1 : GameEngine.Engine {
    }
}
```

Which is inheriting...

```
Public Class Engine
    Inherits Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game

    Protected Overrides Sub Update(GameTime As Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime)
        If GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back = ButtonState.Pressed Then
            Me.Exit()
        End If

        For Each Element In Elements
            Element.Update(GameTime)
        Next

        MyBase.Update(GameTime)
    End Sub

   ...
```

This seems to work and I've been able to load content, render a model, take gamepad input, etc...

So what I'm asking is... Is there really a restriction due to some advanced features not supported in VB.Net or is it merely that no project templates/support are available?

Is there some performance optimisation when compiling to MSIL that the VB compiler misses?

Comment: I've just stumbled across this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2011/05/25/vb-support-for-the-xna-platform.aspx which explains that XNA does/will support VB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XNA does support VB. This was announced back in May of 2011 -> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2011/05/25/vb-support-for-the-xna-platform.aspx

Comment: I got some really useful information from @Polynomial's answer but this is correct (Note the comments on the Q - It was linked this afternoon.)

Answer (score 14):

VB.NET and C# both compile to the same MSIL at a semantic level, so it's not a technical limitation. As you've seen, it's not too difficult to hack together a VB.NET app that accesses XNA.

The restriction is simply because examples have to be written in a particular language by a person, and most professional game developers will be coming from a C++ background. It's a human resource limitation - they can only write so much sample code.

There are also some [performance differences between C# and VB.NET](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/vbnet-vs-c-round-2-pounding-on-performance/1027686), which may have contributed to Microsoft's decision.

**Update:** It also turns out that [VB.NET doesn't support unsafe code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915874/how-can-i-use-unsafe-code-in-vb-net). You'll often find cases where unsafe code is necessary in games programming, for performance reasons. I have a feeling that Microsoft's decision was made based on a compound list of reasons.

Comment: Thanks for a useful answer - I've always known about unsafe code but hadn't realised the significance - can you give an example of when it would be used? I'm guessing faster image manipulation/similar? I'll leave this open a while to see if any other reasons crop up.

Comment: Unsafe math is quite a bit faster, so for shader implementations in C# and image processing, it's a great performance enhancement. You'll also find unsafe code when dealing with external libs that have to be called in a tight loop - the p/invoke overhead is quite high for typesafe code.

Comment: Thanks - I think I'm going to have a go at throwing something together and see how it goes. Worst-case, I can always chuck the unsafe code in a C# library.

Comment: @Polynomial: While I agree it's faster, others should keep in mind that unsafe code cannot deploy to the Xbox 360 from XNA.

Comment: @Nic - Thanks for the info, I hadn't considered this. I suppose a solution to that is to have both safe and unsafe implementations, then use preprocessor conditionals to activate and deactivate the unsafe blocks based on the target platform.

Comment: @Polynomial: That's not a bad idea, I run an XNA game engine that is mostly for PC, I could utilize some unsafe optimizations wrapped in some preprocessor checks to speed things up if needed.