# I have a C# code. I want to convert it in vb.net. But I am unable to convert unsafe and fixed key word

Tags: c#, vb.net, fixed, unsafe

**Unasafe and fixed in vb.net**

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public unsafe struct SGDeviceInfoParam
    {
        private const int SGDEV_SN_LEN = 15;        // Device Serial Number Length

        public UInt32 DeviceID;
```

**Here is problem **                    // 0 - 9

```
public fixed Byte DeviceSN[SGDEV_SN_LEN + 1]; // Device Serial Number, Length of SN = 15
            public UInt32 ComPort;                      // Parallel device=>PP address, USB device=>USB(0x3BC+1)
            public UInt32 ComSpeed;                     // Parallel device=>PP mode, USB device=>0 
            public UInt32 ImageWidth;                   // Image Width
            public UInt32 ImageHeight;                  // Image Height
            public UInt32 Contrast;                     // 0 ~ 100
            public UInt32 Brightness;                   // 0 ~ 100
            public UInt32 Gain;                         // Dependent on each device
            public UInt32 ImageDPI;                     // DPI
            public UInt32 FWVersion;                    // FWVersion
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915874/how-can-i-use-unsafe-code-in-vb-net

Comment: You just don't need a fixed buffer, a regular Byte() array is good enough.  With the `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=SGDEV_SN_LEN+1)>` attribute to tell the pinvoke marshaller what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

**It is my effort but I`m not satisfied**

```
  <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)>
Public Structure SGDeviceInfoParam

    Private Const SGDEV_SN_LEN As Integer = 15

    ' Device Serial Number Length
    Public DeviceID As UInt32

    ' Device Serial Number, Length of SN = 15
    Public ComPort As UInt32

    ' Parallel device=>PP address, USB device=>USB(0x3BC+1)
    Public ComSpeed As UInt32

    ' Parallel device=>PP mode, USB device=>0 
    Public ImageWidth As UInt32

    ' Image Width
    Public ImageHeight As UInt32

    ' Image Height
    Public Contrast As UInt32

    ' 0 ~ 100
    Public Brightness As UInt32

    ' 0 ~ 100
    Public Gain As UInt32

    ' Dependent on each device
    Public ImageDPI As UInt32

    ' DPI
    Public FWVersion As UInt32
End Structure
```