# .NET Compilation Bug?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am coding a library for my own personal use, so I can create other projects faster and more conveniently. Most of the library is written in VB.NET (a simplified version of C#), but since VB.NET includes no capability for unsafe coding, I have written a small portion in C# to handle tasks requiring pointers. Why I mention the VB.NET library will become apparent later in this question.

One of the static classes in my accompanying C# library is a relatively simple function for converting between unmanaged structures. It is as follows:

```
public static unsafe class SurroundingClass
{
    public static T1 ValueToValueBitwise<T0, T1>(T0 Value)
        where T0 : unmanaged
        where T1 : unmanaged
    {
        if (sizeof(T0) != sizeof(T1)) throw new ArgumentException();
        return *(T1*)&Value;
    }
}
```

I apologize if my style of coding is unconventional; I am self-taught.

The function generates no compiler errors in C#, and works magnificently when used by other C# functions. However, events do not progress as smoothly when I reference the function from a VB.NET project. Here is an example of a call to my function in VB.NET:

```
Dim myInt As Integer = ValueToValueBitwise(Of Single, Integer)(13.5!)
```

When I attempt to compile this function with the VB.NET compiler, it fails, providing the rather uninformative excuse "'' is an unsupported type." Usually, when I get this sort of "'' is invalid" error, it is because I have not specified a name or type parameter to a declaration or type argument, respectively. However, this is obviously not the case, as the equivalent function call works flawlessly in C#.
When you hover over a function name with your cursor, Visual Studio gives you a popup with the syntax for calling the function. Interestingly, when I hover over the function name with my cursor, it pops up with the following:
[Visual Studio Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhr2S.png)

At the present time, my best speculation is that VB.NET has no equivalent to C#'s "unmanaged" keyword, and as a result, the VB.NET compiler dies a miserable death. I am looking for either a patch, a workaround, or some other solution.
I am using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6.3, with the .NET framework in both projects set at version 4.8. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what's going on with the vb.net code, but I suspect that [`Unsafe.As<TFrom,TTo>(TFrom) `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.as?view=net-7.0#system-runtime-compilerservices-unsafe-as-2(-0@)) may do what you need.

Comment: Here's an old issue from 2018 that states *We don't support unmanaged types in Visual Basic, even if the type is used in C#.*: [Unable to call C# 7.3 method with unmanaged type parameter #300](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/300).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.singletoint32bits?view=net-7.0

Comment: VB .Net doesn't allow `unsafe` code under any circumstances. see [How can I use unsafe code in VB.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915874/how-can-i-use-unsafe-code-in-vb-net#:~:text=VB.NET%20is%20more%20restrictive,unsafe%20code%20under%20any%20circumstances.&text=Not%20possible%2C%20since%20vb.net%20does%20not%20support%20unsafe%20code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182) explained, VB.NET has no support for unmanaged types. As a result, the types did not qualify, because they were required to inherit from a type that didn't exist in VB.NET. This caused the compiler to throw an error when it attempted compilation.

Thank you for your help!